# cvs2svn: Convert and Place Repository into a Sub-directory of Exisiting SVN Rrepository

Tags: svn, cvs, cvs2svn

I have an existing SVN repository on a Linux machine as `/conf /db /hooks /locks format readme.txt` which looks the following after checking out.

```
MainRepo
 -trunk
 -branches
 -tags
```

I want to do a few CVS to SVN conversions using cvs2svn and retain history and place the new repositories (ProjectA, ProjectB etc) under `MainRepo` as...

```
| MainRepo
     -trunk
     -branches
     -tags
   | SubRepo
      | ProjectA
         -trunk
         -branches
         -tags
      | ProjectB
```

How can I do this ? I have already created the sub-folders /SubRepo/ProjectA using `svn mkdir` .

How to place the converted repo under them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting "trunk_path" (under "run_options.add_project") in the config file?

Comment: No, I am new to this. Can you help me out with the parameters I need to add to the options.

Comment: Their documentation is [here](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html). You'll need to use the options-file method. The sample options file also contains documentation.

Comment: I am using the options file and while it did it correctly for ProjectA ...while doing it for ProjectB its giving error.
`svnadmin: File already exists: filesystem '/opt/svn/MainRepo/db', transaction on '1912-4', path 'trunk'`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that using trunk_path doesn't work for ProjectB (i.e., `trunk_path=SubRepo/ProjectB/trunk`) is that it causes cvs2svn to attempt to create the `SubRepo` and `SubRepo/ProjectA` paths.  But the `SubRepo` path already exists from your import of ProjectA, and this causes `svnadmin load` to fail.

The simplest way to import the rest of your projects would be to [convert each project](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#partialconversion) as if it were going to be a top-level project (with top-level `/trunk`, `/branches`, and `/tags` directories), but write the output to a dumpfile (using cvs2svn's `--dumpfile` option).  Then load the dumpfile into your existing repository using a command like

```
svnadmin load --parent-dir SubRepo/ProjectB <DUMPFILE
```

Comment: Exactly, at the end this is how I had to made it work... Thanks for explaining the reason for the error I was facing.